# Call function after UiApp is loaded (Javascript onLoad equivalent)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a UiApp form that requires some spreadsheet data (slowish retrieval). What I'd like to achieve is load the view as usual and after it has been displayed do something like calling a server handler that gets the data and updates my view when it's done. Is that possible?

I looked around but I didn't find anything.

According to [this](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/other-examples/stock-watcher-reloaded/create-a-uiapp-script), "function doGet(e) is the GWT equivalent of onLoad", but it's not in my case as I would like to dispay the page and *only then* do the slow part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stumbled on this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/2pqhh_eTIvQ) which we could then use to implement a pseudo-onLoad event.

The `setValue` function on checkboxes has [an optional parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_checkbox?hl=en#setValue) to fire the valueChanged handler. So you can programmatically trigger the valueChanged handler, which allows you to return the app (load it initially) while the handler is being invoked simultaneously.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var label = app.createLabel('Loading the data from the spreadsheet.')
                 .setId('statusLabel')
  app.add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('loadData');
  var chk = app.createCheckBox('test').addValueChangeHandler(handler).setVisible(false).setValue(true,true).setId('chk');
  app.add(chk);

  return app;
}

function loadData(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); //placeholder for some function that takes a long time.

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setText("Loaded the data from the spreadsheet");

  return app;
}
```

Comment: that's really a good one ;-) maybe you could add a bit of explanation about the [soft trigger ability of the checkBoxes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_checkbox?hl=en#setValue) that you use

Answer (score 0):

Several other widgets have `setValue(value, fireEvents)` methods, eg. `TextBox`, `PasswordTextBox` etc.  It seems like there is nothing unique about the `CheckBox` widget in implementing this technique.