# why does the first occurrence of a handler call return an undefined value as parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been playing with this small test code that - I admit - isn't very useful but I noticed that the value returned in the `callBackElement` of the first handler is undefined when this handler is called for the first time.

I couldn't figure out why... so I added a condition that solves the problem but I still would like to understand why this is working like that...

The script comes from a idea shown in [this post earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785576/call-function-after-uiapp-is-loaded-javascript-onload-equivalent), I commented the line that causes the error in the script below (it's a bit long, sorry about that) and runs as a sort of timer/counter to illustrate the ability to fire a handler programmatically with checkBoxes.

If someone can explain why this condition is necessary ?

```
    var nn=0;
    //
    function doGet() {
      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('120').setWidth('200').setTitle('Timer/counter test');
      var Panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
      var label = app.createLabel('Initial display')
                     .setId('statusLabel')
      app.add(label);
      var counter = app.createTextBox().setName('counter').setId('counter').setValue('0')
      var handler1 = app.createServerHandler('loadData1').addCallbackElement(Panel);
      var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('loadData2').addCallbackElement(Panel);
      var chk1 = app.createCheckBox('test1').addValueChangeHandler(handler1).setVisible(true).setValue(true,true).setId('chk1');
      var chk2 = app.createCheckBox('test2').addValueChangeHandler(handler2).setVisible(true).setValue(false,false).setId('chk2');
      app.add(Panel.add(chk1).add(chk2).add(counter));
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app)
    }

    function loadData1(e) {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var xx = e.parameter.counter
//*******************************************************
      if(xx){nn = Number(xx)}; // here is the question
    //  nn = Number(xx);       // if I use this line the first occurence = undefined
      nn++
      var cnt = app.getElementById('counter').setValue(nn)
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      var chk1 = app.getElementById('chk1').setValue(false,false)
      var chk2 = app.getElementById('chk2').setValue(true,true)
      var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
      label.setText("Handler 1 :-(");

      return app;
    }

    function loadData2(e) {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var xx = Number(e.parameter.counter)
      xx++
      var cnt = app.getElementById('counter').setValue(xx)
      Utilities.sleep(500); 
      var chk1 = app.getElementById('chk1').setValue(true,true)
      var chk2 = app.getElementById('chk2').setValue(false,false)
      var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
      label.setText("Handler 2 ;-)");

      return app;
    }
```

The app looks like this:

[image]

and is [testable here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwm-LMtqr_PcZHKJBksKVDc8pFoPUVkfRxjd5D9u0YHLCHaeq4f/exec)

**EDIT :** working solution is to fire the handler after adding the widgets to the panel (see Phil's answer)
like this :

```
  var chk1 = app.createCheckBox('test1').addValueChangeHandler(handler1).setVisible(true).setId('chk1');
  var chk2 = app.createCheckBox('test2').addValueChangeHandler(handler2).setVisible(true).setId('chk2');
  app.add(Panel.add(chk1).add(chk2).add(counter));
  chk1.setValue(true,true);
  chk2.setValue(false,false);
  return app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback element which you specified for that handler (`Panel`) has no elements at the time that it is invoked. So you are essentially passing along a empty panel to that handler. So since `chk1` hasn't been added to the panel yet, its value isn't added as a parameter to the handler.

Put `chk1.setValue(true,true)` *after* the call to `Panel.add(chk1)`.

As seen in [this example](http://pastebin.com/QxF6xmUe), the handler is *queued* when `setValue(true,true)` is called. This means that all the parameters that will be passed to the handler are gathered. It looks at the callback elements, reads their values, and then **continues executing the `doGet`**. After `doGet` finishes, the handler is executed.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't imagine that the handler could be called before the 'return' in the doGet function...

Comment: That said, the problem comes probably because the handler is fired immediately... in a "normal" setup (when a user is firing an event) I can add the element after the handler definition without any issue. That's what made me confused because I never tried this special property before... thanks again for the heads up ;-)

Comment: Actually, it looks like the handler is never called before the doGet finishes. [I wrote a test here](http://pastebin.com/PuLXZML8). I could never get the handler to execute before the main thread. This leads me to believe that when you `setValue(true,true)` the handler is *queued* but not executed. [This example](http://pastebin.com/QxF6xmUe) proves that the handler is queued (all the parameters are gathered), but not executed. I will add a note of this in my answer.